# Require.js version individual files

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We have a complex older system and we want to possibly transition to using Require.js
One question I have is whether it is possible to set up specific versions of a file.
I'm not talking about "multiple versions" in the same page.
What I'm thinking is this:

- Module1
- Module2

  - Module1
- Module3

  - Module1
- Module4

  - Module2
  - Module3

I want a way to version Module1 so that I can go and change the version number in a single place.
I know I can use:
`require.config({ urlArgs: "bust=v3" })` but can I do that in the top of the file for Module1 and have it only refer to that Module?

Comment: Are you talking about cache busting, or is there some other reason you want to have a version number?

Comment: I am talking about cache busting, but I want to only "bust the cache" of specific files.  We don't want to update 1 file in our system and have the users redownload another 100 JS files that didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `paths` object in your RequireJS configuration.  This will map a module's name to the URL RequireJS should download.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths

```
paths: {
    'Module1': 'path/to/Module1_v1'
}
```

Comment: But that would require changing the actual filename during versioning right?  Which would cause problems with source control history.  Or could I possibly do: `'Module1': 'path/to/Module1?bust=v2'`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can add URL query arguments to a path because RequireJS needs to add the ".js" suffix to the URL.  At least if you're using Git, renaming files won't break your source control history.

Comment: Sadly, not using Git.  Using Visual Source Safe (really)

Comment: You could use a sym-link and rename that every time you need to bump the version.